# How to scroll image based on the scrollable content text on its right side?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to build app that contains
one image on left side & text on right side

I am trying to set the position to image to be fixed when i scroll the text content & once content is scrolled the image would be stick to that position.

Any thoughts how to do this with jquery & css ?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for position: sticky https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: Yes but it should stay sticky until the certain div is scrolled completely

Answer (score 0):

**Check this fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/4va5doc0/1/

I've used jQuery to set the height of the div which contains all your text, and used it to change the position-value to absolute after you scroll an amount equal to the text-content height. It will then place the image on the exact place where the height of your text-content, and I subtracted the height of the image so it aligns with the bottom part of the image, and not the top. I added another div in the bottom of your HTML so you could test this. I believe this answers your question?

Here is the jQuery added:

```
$(function() {
  //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
  var img = $(".img-fluida");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(".tab_content").height();
    if (scroll >= height - 526) {
      img.css("top", height - "526");
      img.css("position", "absolute");
    } else {
      img.css("position", "fixed");
      img.css("top", "");
    }
  });
});
```

Check the fiddle for the rest, there's some CSS changes as well(minor).

Comment: Thankyou for the answer to the question. Why static size "526" ?

Comment: Because that's the height of the image. It's not static. It takes the height of your content and - (minus) height of image. If this function worked as you wanted, please vote as correct answer.

Comment: Hello. As this solved your question, can you please set it as the answer? Appreciate it :)